# Polymorphic | Self Referentials | Rails Active record models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

> PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "users"
>   violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_fd01e11a00" on table
>   "user_tasks" DETAIL: Key (id)=(4) is still referenced from table
>   "user_tasks". : DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1

A user can assign task to another user. there for I created a through table which joins the task table and self joins the users table. the table look like this:

**| user_id | task_id | to_user_id |**

**UserTask** (migration):

```
class CreateUserTasks  < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_tasks do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :task, foreign_key: true, unique: true
      t.references :to_user, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :user_tasks, :users, column: :to_user_id
    add_index :user_tasks, [:user_id, :to_user_id], unique: false
  end
end
```

and models are as follow:

**User**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**UserTask**:

```
class UserTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :to_user, class_name: "User"
end
```

**Task**:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_tasks
    has_many :users, through: :user_tasks, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :to_users, through: :user_tasks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

the problem is when I try to delete user it produces error **foreign key constraints error that the key is still references from users table**
please help guide me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The UserTask is the join table right?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user_tasks, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks
end
```

i hope it works???

cross finger <3

Answer (score 0):

i think your issue is in the join model, UserTask. I think it should be declared like this, without the commented out line below.:

```
UserTask:

class UserTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
  **#belongs_to :to_user, class_name: "User"**
end
```

Then you should be able to delete a user and the record in the join model,user_task, as you have specified the dependent option correctly.
Check a detailed explanation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html, section Delete or destroy?

Answer (score 0):

**This is solution less Answer:**

Up to my knowledge, after searching over google.com I found that when using `dependent: :destroy` with association it look for object `id` for deleting.

but in my case I am using triple referential as follows

`task` , `user` , `to_user` so the `dependent: :destroy` will delete these association w.r.t each object `id` which will be in our case as `task_id` , `user_id` , `to_user_id`. it will be able to delete `task`, and `user` only but will not delete `to_user_id` because it only knows `user_id` not `to_user_id`